# convert string to date and time as am/pm format

Tags: java, datetime, timestamp

```
 string : 2014-04-25 17:03:13
```

using SimpleDateFormat is enough to format?
or
otherwise i will shift to any new API?

```
Date date = new Date(string);
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd");
out.println( dateFormat.format (date));
```

My expected result is (India zone):

```
Date : 25-04-2014
Time : 05:03 PM
```

Comment: You'll need at least two `SimpleDateFormat` objects - one to parse the initial String, and one (or maybe two) to format the result.

Comment: Either have two date formats... one for time and one for date. Or extend the simpledateformat and add your methods.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Remembering that `Date` objects have no inherent format, you need two `DateFormat` objects to produce the result you seek - one to parse and another to format:

```
String input = "2014-04-25 17:03:13";
DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("'Date : 'dd-MM-yyyy\n'Time : 'KK:mm a");
System.out.println(outputFormat.format(inputFormat.parse(input)));
```

Output:

```
Date : 25-04-2014
Time : 05:03 PM
```

Note the use of quoted sequences in the format, such a `"'Date : '"`, which is treated as a literal within the format pattern.

Comment: actually that string comes from mysql database as datetime data type: rs.getDate("column"); can u please tell me how to handle?

Comment: `getDate()` returns a `java.sql.Date`, which has its time part set to `00:00:00`. Instead use `getTimestamp()`, like this: `outputFormat.format(rs.getTimestamp("column"))`

Comment: can java.sql.Time class object store time in am/pm format. if yes how?

Comment: @Shuddh No Java date-like objects store any formatting information; they all only represent an instant in time (typically a `long` of epoch milliseconds). Formatting is done via Format objects, although there is a default format for them (so their `toString()` works, but a) that's done at the class level (not the instance level) and b) you can't change that anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I custom `onTimeSet()` function . Send the `hour` and `minutes` to it. It will return  the time with `format am and pm`

```
public static String onTimeSet( int hour, int minute) {

    Calendar mCalen = Calendar.getInstance();;
       mCalen.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
       mCalen.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

       int hour12format_local = mCalen.get(Calendar.HOUR);
       int hourOfDay_local = mCalen.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
       int minute_local = mCalen.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
       int ampm = mCalen.get(Calendar.AM_PM);
       String minute1;
       if(minute_local<10){

        minute1="0"+minute_local;
       }
       else
          minute1=""+minute_local;

       String ampmStr = (ampm == 0) ? "AM" : "PM";
       // Set the Time String in Button

       if(hour12format_local==0)
        hour12format_local=12;



String selecteTime=hour12format_local+":"+ minute1+" "+ampmStr;

retrun selecteTime;


}
```

Answer (score 1):

```java
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a");
```

more patterns you can find [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try given below sample code:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = new Date();
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date)); 
//Output: 2013-05-20 10:16:44
```

For more functionalities on Data and Time try [Joda-Time API](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) .