# Error in output while converting date format to AM/PM in Android

Tags: android, date, datetime

i am converting my date received from server **yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss** to **dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss am/pm**

i wrote following code to do it..

```
SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy, hh:mm:ss a", Locale.getDefault());

 String out = "";
 inputFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")); //Also tried GMT+00:00

 Date date = inputFormat.parse(str_date);

 outputFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
 out = outputFormat.format(date);

 L.c("The date format for " + str_date + " is " + out);

 return out;
```

everything works fine except if you note below console log 06:21:48 am, 06:09:44 am and few others shows AM instead of PM.

Is my code wrong? or there any bug?

```
04-02 19:13:37.381    4815-4815/in.dummy.app D/ARR﹕ The date format for 2015-04-02 13:10:19 is 02-04-2015, 06:40:19 pm
04-02 19:13:37.414    4815-4815/in.dummy.app D/ARR﹕ The date format for 2015-04-02 13:02:22 is 02-04-2015, 06:32:22 pm
04-02 19:13:37.436    4815-4815/in.dummy.app D/ARR﹕ The date format for 2015-04-02 12:51:48 is 02-04-2015, 06:21:48 am
04-02 19:13:42.191    4815-4815/in.dummy.app D/ARR﹕ The date format for 2015-04-02 12:39:44 is 02-04-2015, 06:09:44 am
04-02 19:13:43.484    4815-4815/in.dummy.app D/ARR﹕ The date format for 2015-04-02 12:17:48 is 02-04-2015, 05:47:48 am
04-02 19:13:44.990    4815-4815/in.dummy.app D/ARR﹕ The date format for 2015-04-02 12:10:30 is 02-04-2015, 05:40:30 am
04-02 19:13:56.347    4815-4815/in.dummy.app D/ARR﹕ The date format for 2015-04-02 12:00:00 is 02-04-2015, 05:30:00 am
04-02 19:13:57.228    4815-4815/in.dummy.app D/ARR﹕ The date format for 2015-04-02 11:58:13 is 02-04-2015, 05:28:13 pm
04-02 19:13:57.467    4815-4815/in.dummy.app D/ARR﹕ The date format for 2015-04-02 11:55:18 is 02-04-2015, 05:25:18 pm
04-02 19:13:58.332    4815-4815/in.dummy.app D/ARR﹕ The date format for 2015-04-02 11:48:13 is 02-04-2015, 05:18:13 pm
04-02 19:13:58.563    4815-4815/in.dummy.app D/ARR﹕ The date format for 2015-04-02 11:42:28 is 02-04-2015, 05:12:28 pm
04-02 19:14:00.822    4815-4815/in.dummy.app D/ARR﹕ The date format for 2015-04-02 09:54:22 is 02-04-2015, 03:24:22 pm
04-02 19:14:01.009    4815-4815/in.dummy.app D/ARR﹕ The date format for 2015-04-01 11:30:33 is 01-04-2015, 05:00:33 pm
```

Comment: Is the String that your trying to parse actually in UTC before parsing String to Date? And you need to parse out the date in 24 hour format `SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());` if you are converting using UTC

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23751172/convert-string-to-date-and-time-as-am-pm-format

Comment: @inner_class7 i guess.. i am receiving it from the server.. its just giving me date as string in "2015-04-02 12:51:48" format

Comment: @GaurawYadav brother, my question is "Error in ouput" not how to convert date to AM/PM

Comment: What time zone is the server using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

str_date is in 24 hours format

H Hour(0-23),
h Hour in am/pm (1-12)

```
 SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
    "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually date conversion in your code correctly like below

input date : **2015-04-02 13:10:19** // With GMT+00:00

Convert date : **02-04-2015, 01:10:19 PM** // With GMT+00:00

Now convert with Your device default local because you set 
outputFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());

Output date : **02-04-2015, 06:40:19 pm** // With your device Locale. I think your device GMT+05:30

Comment: Thank you..  I found the solution the problem is i am converting incoming date 24hrs as 12hrs
SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault()); // it should be HH not hh..